# Refresh a remote URL with Gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp, livereload, browser-sync, gulp-livereload

I have a gulp task that uploads changed files via FTP, and I'd like it to also trigger a refresh in my browser window. I know there are ways to do this for local sites with modules like browser-sync and live-reload, but I can't seem to find anything that would let me refresh a remote site. It's a minor thing, but it'd be such a nice little convenience.

Is this even possible?

Comment: not an expert but vinyl-fs and http look as tho they preserve the 'local-only' idiom for the file-sys listener that you want ... https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl-fs  .. https://www.npmjs.com/package/vinyl-http